# Backbone Sync with a mashup of models in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a rails controller which sends a mash-up of models as a global json object. Something like this

```
{
  dogs : { species: {}, ...},
  cats : { food: {}, ...},
  foxes : { },
  ...,
  ...
}
```

On my client side, I have all these entities neatly segregated out into different backbone models and backbone collections.

On some onchange event, I need to send a mashup of some model attributes back to the server as a HTTP POST request and the server sends a response which again spans values across a few models.

How do I setup Backbone.sync to deal with such an ajax scenario? I do not want to change the rails backend because its quite a steady implementation. Or do I make vanilla $.ajax requests through jQuery in one of my backbone views and handle it in a callback on ajax success/failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of ways to do this via backbone.  I think I'd start out with a model to represent the mashup:

```
var MashupModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
});
```

Then you can pass in any models like you would normally (or a collection for that matter):

```
var my_mash = new MashupModel({
  dog:   dogModel.toJSON(),
  cat:   catModel.toJSON(),
  foxes: foxCollection.toJSON()
});
// do stuff if you need...
```

Then do what you want when the response comes back like normal:

```
my_mash.save({}, {
  success: function(model, response) {
    // do stuff here to put new data into the proper models / collections
  },
  error: function() { alert("I FAIL!"); }
});
```

That's all well and good... however, I think it would be better to push the above down into the MashupModel object instead of at the request level.  Again, several ways:

```
var MashupModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(attrs) {
    // can't remember the actual code, but something along the lines of:
    _.each( attrs.keys, function(key) {
      this.set(key, attrs.key.toJSON();
    });
  },

  save: function(attrs, opts) {
    var callback = opts.success;
    opts.success = function(model, response) {
      // do your conversion from json data to models / collections
      callback(model, response);
    };
    // now call 'super'
    // (ala: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-extend)
    Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attrs, opts);
  }
});
```

Or you could override toJSON (since backbone calls that to get the attrs ready for ajax):

```
// class definition like above, no initilize...
...
toJSON: function() {
  // again, this is pseudocode-y
  var attrs = {};
  _.each( this.attributes.keys, function() {
    attrs.key = this.attributes.key.toJSON();
  });
  return attrs;
}
...
// save: would be the same as above, cept you'd be updating the models
// directly through this.get('dogs').whatever...
```

Now, you can just do:

```
var my_mash = new MashupModel({
  dog:    dogModel,
  cat:    catModel,
  foxes:  foxCollection
});
// do some stuff...

my_mash.save({}, {
  success: function(model, response) {
    // now only do stuff specific to this save action, like update some views...
  },
  error: function() { alert("I FAIL!"); }
```

Comment: Very interesting. I was tempted to create an abstracted Backbone Model like your MashupModel but polled the community before that. I think I will give it a try and report back how the experiment went and probably accept your answer then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

it would be possible, but may be difficult to modify backbone.sync to work with this structure. i'd recommend going with plain old jquery $.ajax requests. then on success, pull the info apart and populate your collections.

```
$.get("/whatever", function(data){
  catCollection.reset(data.cats);
  dogCollection.reset(data.dogs);
  // etc
});


data = {};
data.cats = catCollection.toJSON();
data.dogs = dogCollection.toJSON();
// etc
$.post("/whatever", data);
```